# Acceptability of asking why several other people left a position?

Tags: resignation

I am currently working at a part time job at company. I know that the position isn't new. And I know that people left voluntarily from this position. I think I know why after working a month with this company. But I would like to make sure since I am not doing great. I make mistakes, and I am slow learner. But I am suspecting that some of them are sabotage attempts. Machines have changed settings when it is my turn to use them (even though the machines should never had their setting changed). I get blamed for stuff that I have no memory of.

Comment: I've edited the title a bit to make it a tad more on topic and sound less of asking purely subjective opinion.

Comment: The full time workers  seem to like to blame the part time workers to get them fired.  Doing this allows them to keep their job.

Comment: Why would someone who is "after you" decide to reveal that the others before you were fired because they sabotaged their computers with different settings? If you can answer that, then you can ask.

Answer (score 2):

It's not rude.  But you have to be very diplomatic about it.  You have to be very, very careful who you ask.  Don't let anyone be able to label you as a complainer.  Be solution-oriented.

As for the blame game - if it's with machine settings, doing a little cover-your-behind will work in the short term.  When you finish working with a device, snap a picture of the controls or settings with your phone (I'm assuming).  When the fingers are pointed at you, pull out your phone.  This is only a short term strategy though - if the company just has a blaming type culture, then you need to get out of there if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: I am not sure if I am allowed to take pictures. I think that could be a breach of company privacy...There are CCTVs but I do not think it is appropriate to ask for CCTV footage..

Answer (score 0):

If you have recognised a possible reason things are going wrong, work on mitigating it. If you can, 'lock' the settings. If you can't, find a way to log changes.

Complaining however tactfully without anything but a hunch is not going to work out well. These are computers I can tell almost anything that was done to one of them because the logs keep records which are timestamped to the second. If I was so inclined I could monitor even more closely than that.